# java Display even integers between X and Y?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop, integer

I am new to java and stuck on this problem . I have only done the java scanner part where you enter the two integers and I am so lost. The problem says make a java class that allows a user to input  two integers and displays  EVEN integers between them. Display/print There are no EVEN integers between X and Y if there are no even integers between the entered values.
If their are even integers between the two numbers entered then the program should say the numbers between X and Y are: (then the even numbers including X and Y).
In advance thank you for your help.

Comment: @user16320675 I only have the scanner part done but my question is if I enter two integers and their is no even integer between them how would I display that and also how would I display the even integers between the two numbers I entered? Sorry for the beginner question but I have only done java for 2 weeks.

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll want to get the two inputs, determine which is smaller and which is bigger, then you will want to make a for-i loop to set i as your low number, and the loop ending deciding factor is that i will equal the high number, as long as i is lower than the higher number, it will increase (i++). Within the loop, you will check each number which is i as it increments if it is divisible by 2, but by using the modular operator it will divide the 2 over and over till it reaches what would be left over, all even numbers are divided by 2 over and over till it reaches 0. Once the IF statement is true, it will print the number (i).

```
class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        // Declare objects and variables.
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int low, high;

        // Ask user for input, and initialize variables.
        System.out.println("Enter an integer:");
        low = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter another integer:");
        high = scan.nextInt();

        //Checks which is high or low, and swaps if low is bigger than high using a temporary variable.
        if (low > high){
            int temp = low;
            low = high;
            high = temp;
        }

        System.out.println("\nEVEN numbers between 2 inputs:");
        // For-i loop from low to high finding even numbers to print, i is your counter.
        for (int i = low ; i <= high ; i++) {
            
            // Check's if i is divisible by 2 using the modular operator, any that are true are even.
            if (i % 2 == 0){
                System.out.print(i + " ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Enter an integer:
20
Enter another integer:
12

EVEN numbers between 2 inputs:
12 14 16 18 20
```